# netcat shell bind with mac (command -e not found)

Tags: mac, linux-mint, netcat

I can successfuly use the command nc 192.168.*.* 5442 to connect to a listening device. The device listen using the: nc -lvp 5442. Everything works, I can send messages and receive some. I wanted to create a remote shell with it. Option -e is not found! Any idea why and how to fix it? The other machine I am using is mint17.2 and the command -e is also not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most operating systems are packaged with a version of netcat that the -e option has been removed for security reasons. If you need netcat with -e option you have to find a version that includes the execution option or you can compile from source.

You can take a look at [this video](https://hak5.org/episodes/haktip-81)